# Draw things on Canvas in Java

Tags: java, canvas, draw

I have a list of Entity object, I want to draw all of them using Graphics2D object on a canvas but some objects must be drawn over others if they are at the same position, I have one solution like this:

```
    for(Entity e : cloneEntities)
        if (e instanceof Dirty) e.render(g);
    for(Entity e : cloneEntities)
        if (e instanceof Box) e.render(g);
    for(Entity e : cloneEntities)
        if (e instanceof RunObstacle) e.render(g);
```

but it's seem like massive. Anyone have other solution for this situation? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to @patrick-hainge 's answer, you could add a field in `Entity` called `z-index` of type `int` that gets set in the constructor of `Entity`.  Therefore, your child constructor would be required to send it a value.

Then you would just sort the `cloneEntities` list before calling render on each like so:

```
clonedEntities.stream().sort((a,b)->a.getZindex()-b.getZindex()).forEach((a)->a.render(g));
```

**Note**

This will only work if `cloneEntities` is declared as a `List` and not a `Set`

Comment: Could be a good idea to also have `z-index` as a constant (so `public static final`) so we can just address them directly and not have to call `getZindex()` a whole load of times. Probably a marginal performance gain but given that you're presumably writing a game in Java it's worth bearing in mind.

Comment: I have tried that before for other things in game programming (textureId), but I always run into the same problem.  Making it static removes the context to the object therefore there is no way to call the static method from the parent object without using `.getClass()` on the parent object.  Not entirely sure of the details, but I believe that uses Reflection so the performance gain may cancel itself out because Reflection is heavy

Comment: Hadn't thought of that, thanks. What about having our superclass implement `Comparable<Entity>` and overriding the `compareTo` method to address the `z-index` field of the other `Entity` directly (assuming we set the access of z-index to `protected`)?

Comment: And an explanation for "cloneEntities" object, it's a problem too, when I access Entities List to render each object in it, I got this problem : 

Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
 at Main.Floor.render(Floor.java:54)
 at Main.Game.render(Game.java:102)
 at Main.Game.run(Game.java:159)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Sounds like you're running multiple threads whether you're meaning to or not.  The solution for that problem is out of the scope of this question.  Do a good search on "concurrent modification exception Java List" and you'll find plenty of help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could sort `cloneEntities` by type (you might need a custom Comparator to specify ordering) and then render them all in order. This does much the same thing but *might* save some computations.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution is to create a few BufferedImages for Front, Middle and Background:

```
BufferedImage dirties = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Buffered Image boxes = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)
BufferedImage obstacles = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

for(Entity e : cloneEntities){
    if (e instanceof Dirty) e.render(dirties.getGraphics());
    if (e instanceof Box) e.render(boxes.getGraphics());
    if (e instanceof RunObstacle) e.render(obstacles.getGraphics());
}
//And then render all Layers
 g.drawImage(dirties, 0, 0, width, height, null);
 g.drawImage(boxes, 0, 0, width, height, null);
 g.drawImage(obstacles, 0, 0, width, height, null);
```

This solution is by [Multiple independent layers in Graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974972/multiple-independent-layers-in-graphics).